# How to install ROS on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, ros

Im running Ubuntu 18.04 and trying to install ROS for the first time on my machine. I have tried to follow the instructions at: http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu

I get stuck at this part.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full
```

My attempts:

```
sudo apt -f install

sudo apt update --fix-missing

sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove--reinstreq

sudo apt clean

sudo apt update

sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock

sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Nothing has worked so far.

Terminal commands:

```
$sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full
Reading package lists… Finished
Builds dependency trees
Reading state information ... Finished
Some packages could not be installed. It may mean that you have requested
an impossible situation or, if you use the unstable distribution
that some necessary packages have not yet been created or moved
from "Incoming".
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have dependencies that cannot be satisfied:
 rose-melodic-desktop-full: Dependent on: rose-melodic-desktop but it will not be installed
                            Depending on: rose-melodic-perception but it will not be installed
                            Depending on: rose-melodic-simulators but it will not be installed
                            Depending on: ros-melodic-urdf-sim-tutorial but it will not be installed
E: Could not correct the problems, you have withheld broken packages.
```

Please help me install ROS

Comment: This was the answer for me: Use [aptitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45335914/ros-installation-error-ros-kinetic-in-ubuntu-16-04/58581261#58581261)

Answer (score 0):

first of all install program on ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

after update packet try follow the instructions at: [enter link description here](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu) again

Comment: Try this : sudo apt autoclean, sudo apt-get clean, sudo apt autoremove

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the tip, something atleast happend with the commands you prupose. But im stil stuck at the same error after :
sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full

Comment: Hi, I understand that is something is wrong in packet unused in ubuntu make error.

Comment: Yes but i cannot clear ros package and re download it, only gives same error. Shiuld i  add dependices seperatly, if so how?

Comment: If you post an answer, please add **all** relevant information to the answer itself

Answer (score 0):

1 - After following ROS melodic Installation first steps (see link below), Try to install it with the link "**click here**" below the "**sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full**" line

[ROS melodic Installation page](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu)

If it's doesn't work

2 - check, "**Software & Update**" parameters 
(if you cannot find it: launch "**Ubuntu Software Center**" and in the menu bar, on top, select "**Software & Update**")
In "**Other Sofware**" tab, the link

"**http://pacckage.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic main**"

is printed, and in "**Autentication**" tab a key from **Open Robotics** is printed

3 - Try to do 1- again, if it doesn't work, follow 4-

4 - In "**Updates**" tab, check "**recommanded Updates**", launch  "**Update Manager**" and install updates (I don't do it properly on my PC)

5 - And finally you need to install manually **rosdep** with:
"**sudo apt-get install python-rosdep**"

Answer (score 0):

I got it working like so:

1. Install deps:

   sudo apt install gazebo9-common libgazebo9-dev gazebo9 ros-melodic-gazebo-ros-pkgs ros-melodic-gazebo-dev ros-melodic-gazebo-ros-control ros-melodic-gazebo-ros ros-melodic-urdf-sim-tutorial ros-melodic-simulators
2. Install ros melodic

   sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full